# How to change the color of an object with color in xml eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, object, colors

How to change the color of an object with color in xml eclipse
example

[image]

Comment: you have to be a little more specific, please post your code...

Comment: Please try to explain you question with more details.

Comment: I do not have a code
Can you give me an example code

Comment: XML on its own means nothing here. XML is just a file format specification and does not say what the contents actually mean. So you need to tell us what is using the XML - is this Android for example or JavaFX or ????